# UISearchBar displaying data UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardisplaycontrol

I'm trying understand searchbar I have an api And when I send the api 'where' its giving me some data.
But when I tap the return key.I get nothing.

there is my code.

```
    - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
    [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    NSString *urlPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://test.com/api/index.php"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"process":@"search_record",@"where": self.searchBar.text};
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

    [manager setSecurityPolicy:securityPolicy];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:urlPath parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

        self.customerCards = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSArray *customersArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"customer_list"];
        NSLog(@"%@",customersArray);
        for (NSDictionary *customersDictionary in customersArray) {
            ApiClass *customer = [ApiClass customersWithTitle:[customersDictionary objectForKey:@"adi"]];
            customer.tel = [customersDictionary objectForKey:@"tel"];

            [self.customerCards addObject:customer];

        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"GET: %@", string);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];


}
```

what should I do.

Thanks

Comment: You have asked the same question previously.

Comment: No,That was different.I'm just asking where is the uisearchbar action.And I reply that question.

Comment: You are getting the data when you are tapping on the search button. What is next you want

Comment: No I cant get search data when I tapped search button.I just want to get data when I tap search button.

Comment: Have you added delegate to the file's owner for UISearchBar?

Comment: reload your table in main thread